# Is it safe to call c_str() directly on returned std::string from a function?

Tags: c++

```
int main () {
   char dest[BIG_ENOUGH];
   memset(dest, '\0', sizeof(dest));
   strcpy(dest, func1().c_str());
   return(0);
}
std::string func1 () {
  std::string s("test");
  return s;
}
```

one of my workmates told me that the string on which `c_str()` is invoked may already be destroyed before `strcpy` being executed.

is this true when:

1. compiled with msvc 2008(c++98) ,
2. or compiled with gcc(c++11),
3. or compiled with clang(c++11)?

Comment: This is safe. Note that instead of `memset`, you could do `char dest[BIG_ENOUGH] = {0};`. Also note that zeroing destination is not required for `strcpy`.

Comment: Your workmate is incorrect.   The string returned by `func1()` will exist until the end of the statement - so it (and the data pointed to by the call of `c_str()`) will be destroyed after  the call `strcpy()` has completed.     However, unless you have a specific requirement, `dest` should also be of type `std::string` as well.   Then all `main()` needs to do is `std::string dest;  dest = func1();`  or (even more simply to get the same result, although the mechanics change slightly) `std::string dest = func1()`.

Comment: @Peter the above `main` is just a demo. I will do business operations on `dest` char array before `main`'s  return. thanks for your reply!

Comment: @redhatlinux10 - But that's my point.   You don't need to do "business operations" using an array of `char`.    You can do a lot of those operations directly on elements of the string.   Worst case, create a `std::vector<char>` from the string, and do operations on elements of the vector (or pass the address of it's first element to a function expecting a `char *`).   Either approach is safer, avoids need to hard-code length, avoids needs to explicitly allocate/initialise/deallocate memory, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is safe in the given example as the lifetime of the returned string ends at the end of the statement containing the function call.

In general I recommend reading https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime